# Listens for stopping and starting of process

Tags: java

Is there any way for a Java application on Windows to be notified when a process stops and starts - for example listen to when MS Word starts and stops?

Comment: Well a simple way in Java is to have a background thread that wakes every 5 secs or so and looks at the list of running processes ... but i has hoping there would be a more sophisticated library available.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way for *any application* on Windows to be notified when a process stops and starts? If so, use [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) (or the more convenient [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) wrapper) to access that OS-specific functionality.